# std::vector is very slow?

Tags: c++, vector, performance

Here is what I'm doing.

I have a class which I instance and it has a std::vector.

when I first instance the class this std::vector is empty.

The way I use it is I exponentially add to it and clear. Ex:

Add a number, clear the vector:

Add 2 numbers, clear the vector:

Add 3 numbers, clear the vector,

Add 4 numbers, clear the vector.
......

Is a std::vector the bst way to do what I'm doing?
I tried to do reserve(100,000)  in the constructor but this did not help.

Is there maybe a better container for my usage?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm adding points and creating bezier shapes.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with your algorithm and not your data structure?

Comment: How are you using your class? A class with a very large vector inside is not going to behave nicely if you make copies of it all the time (like if you pass by value rather than reference). Show some more code on how your class is being used.

Comment: As you describe it, you're just pushing numbers onto a vector and doing nothing with them. A better container to use or general way of doing things is largely dependent on what you're trying to do. At least some basic idea of what you're trying to use a vector for will yield better answers.

Comment: Anti Grain Geometry clears each time,

Comment: Which compiler are you using? And what does your actual code look like?

Comment: Are you always adding points at the end of the vector (with `push_back`), or are you adding points in the middle?

Comment: Calling `reserve` should help. Can you post some code?

Comment: Observe the confusion caused by insufficient information. You know things we don't, and you must realize it sounds quite trivial and useless to add things to a vector just to clear them. Are you doing something between those events? What's the vector data for? *What's the bigger picture?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your algorithm appears to be quadratic. If you really need 100,000 elements, you're adding an element 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 100,000 times. That's about 5,000,000,000 operations. That many operations, no matter how trivial they are, will take a while on a standard pc, regardless of whether you're using `std::vector` or hand-crafted assembly language.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
struct A {
   std::vector <int> v;
   A() : v(100000) {}
};
```

is probably what you want. When you say:

```
A a;
```

This creates an instance the struct A (works for classes too) containing a vector of the required size.